# Is watchers looking for all scope variables OR just for variables which are used in view?

Tags: angularjs, scope

I am trying to improve performance of my angularjs project.I am also read that ,for better performance number of watchers on a page should be limited to 2000.
So my questions is,

Actually do watchers really watching for all variables defined to scope(like $scope.name  variable ) OR just for scope variables bound to view?

Thanks for all the answers...

Answer (score -1):

actually watchers DONT LOOKUPS on scope variables. when angular $digest cycle runs( in case of server response or button clicked or ...) , all of watchers runs,and check if last value of that watched variables changes or not, based on this condition watch handlers may be run or not.
so the numbers of $scope variables does not matters.
* with a correct design you can stop using $watchs.